# Parsing JSON to create a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I have the following code which i cannot seem to create a `def` out of:

I have a Json file some of which looks like this:

```
{'records': {'expiryDates': ['05-Aug-2021', '12-Aug-2021', '18-Aug-2021', '26-Aug-2021', '02-Sep-2021', '09-Sep-2021', '16-Sep-2021', '23-Sep-2021', '30-Sep-2021', '28-Oct-2021', '30-Dec-2021', '31-Mar-2022', '30-Jun-2022', '29-Dec-2022', '29-Jun-2023', '28-Dec-2023', '27-Jun-2024', '26-Dec-2024', '26-Jun-2025'], 'data': [{'strikePrice': 7500, 'expiryDate': '29-Dec-2022', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 7500, 'expiryDate': '29-Dec-2022', 'underlying': 'NIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY29-12-2022PE7500.00', 'openInterest': 21, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 235, 'change': 0, 'pChange': 0, 'totalBuyQuantity': 2800, 'totalSellQuantity': 0, 'bidQty': 2800, 'bidprice': 5.85, 'askQty': 0, 'askPrice': 0, 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}}, {'strikePrice': 8000, 'expiryDate': '30-Dec-2021', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 8000, 'expiryDate': '30-Dec-2021', 'underlying': 'NIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY30-12-2021PE8000.00', 'openInterest': 21, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 3.1, 'change': 0, 'pChange': 0, 'totalBuyQuantity': 6850, 'totalSellQuantity': 0, 'bidQty': 1650, 'bidprice': 3.05, 'askQty': 0, 'askPrice': 0, 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}}, {'strikePrice': 8300, 'expiryDate': '30-Jun-2022', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 8300, 'expiryDate': '30-Jun-2022', 'underlying': 'NIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY30-06-2022PE8300.00', 'openInterest': 3, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 4.7, 'change': 0, 'pChange': 0, 'totalBuyQuantity': 2500, 'totalSellQuantity': 0, 'bidQty': 2500, 'bidprice': 0.25, 'askQty': 0, 'askPrice': 0, 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}}, {'strikePrice': 8500, 'expiryDate': '30-Dec-2021', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 8500, 'expiryDate': '30-Dec-2021', 'underlying': 'NIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY30-12-2021PE8500.00', 'openInterest': 199.5, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 3.25, 'change': 0, 'pChange': 0, 'totalBuyQuantity': 7600, 'totalSellQuantity': 0, 'bidQty': 1500, 'bidprice': 3.05, 'askQty': 0, 'askPrice': 0, 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}}, {'strikePrice': 8500, 'expiryDate': '29-Dec-2022', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 8500, 'expiryDate': '29-Dec-2022', 'underlying': 'NIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY29-12-2022PE8500.00', 'openInterest': 2254, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 22.9, 'change': 0, 'pChange': 0, 'totalBuyQuantity': 2850, 'totalSellQuantity': 0, 'bidQty': 2800, 'bidprice': 18.55, 'askQty': 0, 'askPrice': 0, 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}},
```

To access the data i have:

```
access_records_data = data['records']
```

So this produces something like this:

```
{'expiryDates': ['05-Aug-2021',
  '12-Aug-2021',
  '18-Aug-2021',
  '26-Aug-2021',
  '02-Sep-2021',
  '09-Sep-2021',
  '16-Sep-2021',
  '23-Sep-2021',
  '30-Sep-2021',
  '28-Oct-2021',
  '30-Dec-2021',
  '31-Mar-2022',
  '30-Jun-2022',
  '29-Dec-2022',
  '29-Jun-2023',
  '28-Dec-2023',
  '27-Jun-2024',
  '26-Dec-2024',
  '26-Jun-2025'],
 'data': [{'strikePrice': 7500,
   'expiryDate': '29-Dec-2022',
   'PE': {'strikePrice': 7500,
    'expiryDate': '29-Dec-2022',
    'underlying': 'NIFTY',
    'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY29-12-2022PE7500.00',
    'openInterest': 21,
    'changeinOpenInterest': 0,
    'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0,
    'totalTradedVolume': 0,
    'impliedVolatility': 0,
    'lastPrice': 235,
    'change': 0,
    'pChange': 0,
    'totalBuyQuantity': 2800,
    'totalSellQuantity': 0,
    'bidQty': 2800,
    'bidprice': 5.85,
    'askQty': 0,
    'askPrice': 0,
    'underlyingValue': 16130.75}},
```

Great this is working! Next to access the data inside the records i have this:

```
question_access = access_records_data['data']
```

which produces this :

```
question_access

    {'strikePrice': 15500,
  'expiryDate': '31-Mar-2022',
  'CE': {'strikePrice': 15500,
   'expiryDate': '31-Mar-2022',
   'underlying': 'NIFTY',
   'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY31-03-2022CE15500.00',
   'openInterest': 0,
   'changeinOpenInterest': 0,
   'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0,
   'totalTradedVolume': 0,
   'impliedVolatility': 0,
   'lastPrice': 0,
   'change': 0,
   'pChange': 0,
   'totalBuyQuantity': 100,
   'totalSellQuantity': 350,
   'bidQty': 50,
   'bidprice': 1150,
   'askQty': 100,
   'askPrice': 2299.9,
   'underlyingValue': 16130.75},
  'PE': {'strikePrice': 15500,
   'expiryDate': '31-Mar-2022',
   'underlying': 'NIFTY',
   'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY31-03-2022PE15500.00',
   'openInterest': 11,
   'changeinOpenInterest': 0,
   'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0,
   'totalTradedVolume': 0,
   'impliedVolatility': 0,
   'lastPrice': 497.05,
   'change': 0,
   'pChange': 0,
   'totalBuyQuantity': 0,
   'totalSellQuantity': 50,
   'bidQty': 0,
   'bidprice': 0,
   'askQty': 50,
   'askPrice': 470,
   'underlyingValue': 16130.75}},
```

Note i am not pasting the entire data because it is very long but i just wanted to to understand what results i am getting. Next I use this list to get to all the keys i can use in the dict in the list. To do this i have done this:

```
for question_data in question_access:
    print(question_data)
```

Which produces:

```
{'strikePrice': 18500, 'expiryDate': '27-Jun-2024', 'CE': {'strikePrice': 18500, 'expiryDate': '27-Jun-2024', 'underlying': 'NIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY27-06-2024CE18500.00', 'openInterest': 3, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 1810, 'change': 0, 'pChange': 0, 'totalBuyQuantity': 0, 'totalSellQuantity': 500, 'bidQty': 0, 'bidprice': 0, 'askQty': 500, 'askPrice': 1814.6, 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}}
```

Next to get to CE data which i am interested in:

```
   CE_access = question_data['CE']
which contains this data:
{'strikePrice': 18500,
 'expiryDate': '27-Jun-2024',
 'underlying': 'NIFTY',
 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY27-06-2024CE18500.00',
 'openInterest': 3,
 'changeinOpenInterest': 0,
 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0,
 'totalTradedVolume': 0,
 'impliedVolatility': 0,
 'lastPrice': 1810,
 'change': 0,
 'pChange': 0,
 'totalBuyQuantity': 0,
 'totalSellQuantity': 500,
 'bidQty': 0,
 'bidprice': 0,
 'askQty': 500,
 'askPrice': 1814.6,
 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}
```

Finally if i do something like this:

```
CE_access['askQty']
```

it produces this `500`. This is the result which i was looking for. So what i am trying to do is working. Next my plan was to use this code and produce a function. To do this i had done the following:

The code is :

```
def ask_price():
    access_records_data = data['records']
    question_access = access_records_data['data']
    for question_data in question_access:
        CE_access = question_data['CE']
         [there is another for loop here for CE_access]
```

i get this error :

```
<ipython-input-306-153b641331d7> in ask_price()
      3     question_access = access_records_data['data']
      4     for question_data in question_access:
----> 5         CE_access = question_data['CE']
      6 

KeyError: 'CE'
```

I have been beating my head over this code for a while now and have not been able to make any progress, please help me. Why am i getting this error, the code above before the function is working.

Edit :

```
print(question_data)


{'strikePrice': 18500, 'expiryDate': '27-Jun-2024', 'CE': {'strikePrice': 18500, 'expiryDate': '27-Jun-2024', 'underlying': 'NIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXNIFTY27-06-2024CE18500.00', 'openInterest': 3, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 1810, 'change': 0, 'pChange': 0, 'totalBuyQuantity': 0, 'totalSellQuantity': 500, 'bidQty': 0, 'bidprice': 0, 'askQty': 500, 'askPrice': 1814.6, 'underlyingValue': 16130.75}}
```

Comment: It is *pretty clear* why you are getting the error, because one of your `question_data` dict's *doesn't have a `"CE"` key*. You've only posted partial data (if you **are** going to do that, you should make sure it is **actually a complete** example, something we can *use* and doesn't just cut-off somewhere that renders it invalid source code). So not sure what else to tell you. Did you try to `print(question_data)` which should print the offending dict (assuming you are in an IPython repl given the error output...) what does that show you?

Comment: Please post a valid json that we can copy-paste.

Comment: Note, in your printout, the key is actually `"PE"` not `"CE"`...

Comment: Here is the complete file: https://ufile.io/2jwkvsdw

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thats only because i have not posted the entire output. But yes you are right. I will correct it. The entire output has both CE and PE values in it

Comment: How is this creating a function? Functions are *code*.

Comment: @martineau I dont understand. Could you please elaborate. the function is `def ask_price():`

Comment: In Python functions are created starting with `def function_name` followed by Python statements that do things — you know **code**.

Comment: @Slartibartfast well then, it should be obvious, for some of the dicts, there is no "CE" key and in some there is a "PE" key. You need to handle those cases.

Comment: Your question isn't "How do I create a function...". You already have. Your question is "why do I get this KeyError", and most of the text in your post is not relevant to that question. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mre]. Clearly, there are elements in `question_access` that do not have a key called `'CE'`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in the compete data file which i have shared. PE and CE is there for all. It cannot be some case not having PE or CE

Comment: This is what you claim, but *the error message implies differently*. I'm going to go out on a limb and trust the error message correctly reflects what's going on. Again, did you **try printing the offending dict to examine its contents?** What do you see?

Comment: Your question sounds like you want to create a function (dynamically) based on what's in some JSON data that's being parsed.

Comment: @martineau I'm guessing they meant "Creating a function to parse json data"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have posted an edit for `print(question_data)`

Comment: Yes i am just trying to parse the json data

Comment: @Slartibartfast that clearly has a key `'CE'` and isn't the one that causes the error. Instead of printing all `question_data`, do this: `if 'CE' not in question_data: print(question_data)`

Comment: @Slartibartfast - See the structure of your json file. Some dicts have only PE and some have only CE. No dictionaries have both.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It does not output anything

Comment: @not_speshal I thought that could not happen but what can i do to resolve this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you were right earlier. Thanks for your your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries in your json file either have "PE" or "CE" keys. No dictionary has both.

You could use `get` to access the dictionary values which automatically returns `None` if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Try something like this:

```
for question_data in data['records']['data']:
    if question_data.get('CE'):
        print(question_data.get('CE')['askQty'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me meditate on `.get`

Comment: @Slartibartfast this is generally not the way, instead, use `if "CE" in question_data:` instead, then use `print(question_data["CE"]["askQty"]`

Comment: Actually "the Pythonic way" would be to put the `CE_access = question_data['CE']` inside a `try` / `except KeyError:` clause and perform some alternative action when it's not there.